# I keep getting newRow() (the name of my function) not defined

Tags: javascript

http://codepen.io/j4ysen/pen/EiDyj

Entering the `ingredient` fields correctly is supposed to create a new row, however I keep getting an `uncaught error` saying that the function itself is not defined when the red `+` button is pressed.

Anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 67 of your JS, remove the semicolon. Or more appropriately, move it to the end of line 66.

Change this

```
if(ingredient_name === "" || ingredient_amount === "" || ingredient_unit === "Select" ){
    console.log("One or more fields weren't entered")
};
```

To this

```
if(ingredient_name === "" || ingredient_amount === "" || ingredient_unit === "Select" ){
    console.log("One or more fields weren't entered");
}
```